# Problem with Custom Column Value saving

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, php-5.4, sales

I have created the custom column from `sales/order_item` and `sales/quote_item` table. But when I have set the values it's not saving. I don't know what happening. There is no Error logs also.

**My code is**

**mysql4-installer-1.0.0.php**

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$this->_conn->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_quote_item'), 'vendor', 'text');
$this->_conn->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_order_item'), 'vendor', 'text');

$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

**config.xml** file

```
<events>

            <sales_order_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <save_before>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>vendor/observer</class>
                        <method>SaveBefore</method>
                    </save_before>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_before>
            <sales_quote_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <save_quote_before>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>vendor/observer</class>
                        <method>SaveQuoteBefore</method>
                    </save_quote_before>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_save_before>
        </events>
```

**Observer.php** file

```
<?php
    class Easylife_Vendor_Model_Observer
    {               

        public function SaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

            $order_item = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach($order_item as $order_items){
                $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($order_items->getProductId());
                $product->setVendor('Admin');

            }

        }

        public function SaveQuoteBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
                $Product = $item->getProduct();
                $Product->setVendor('Admin');
                $Product->save();
            }
        }

    }
```

Is this method is correct or wrong?

Suggest me how to save this value to those tables..

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using setDropShipVendor (not setVendor) when you add column 'vendor'?

Comment: @michael, Actually I forget, Previously i have used that field now see I have changed. till not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with this code in **Observer.php**:

```
public function SaveQuoteBefore($observer){
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
        $item->setVendor('Admin');
    }
}
```

and remove `function SaveBefore`.In **config.xml** remove `<sales_order_save_before>` and add this code in `<global>`:

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <vendor>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
        </vendor>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
</fieldsets>
```

Don't forget to Flush Cache and maybe Reindex before using it.

Only recommendation - it's better to not use full table name but `$this->getTable('sales/quote_item')` and `$this->getTable('sales/order_item')`.